# Select a submit button of a form that received a change() event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need to build a jQuery script that would select a `button` with `type=submit` of a form that receives a `change()` event.

This is the code I've come up with:

```
var categoryEditForms = $('form.category-edit-block');
categoryEditForms.change(function(form) {
    var submitButton = $(form).find('button[type=submit]');
});
```

After running this code `categoryEditForms` include 4 forms that are present on the page. `submitButton` is a JS object of `length` equal 0. I will only add that the submit button exists inside every form on a page.

How should I amend my code to grap the desired submit button?

Comment: can you add jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `form` variable in your `change` event is the **event itself NOT the form**. Use `this` to retrieve the parent form:

```
var categoryEditForms = $('form.category-edit-block');
categoryEditForms.change(function() {
    var submitButton = $(this).parents("form").find('button[type=submit]');
});
```

A better idea would be to delegate your events though so you only have one `event`, something like:

```
categoryEditForms.on("change", function() {
    var submitButton = $(this).parents("form").find('button[type=submit]');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the right answer. I was just wondering. How does the second method (delegating) make it better? Could you possibly elaborate on it?

Comment: @luqo33 No problems, basically let's say for example you had 100 form category edit blocks on your page, then you used the first code. That would mean that there is actually 100 events. When you delegate (using the second function), there is only ever 1 event. This can drastically improve performance especially when there are lots of elements on the page tied to the same events

Answer (score 0):

You have to traverse the DOM to find the submit button :

```
var categoryEditForms = $('form.category-edit-block');
categoryEditForms.change(function() {
    var submitButton = $(this).parents('form').eq(0).find('button[type=submit]');
});
```